# Far Cry 4 Disc Install Issue

Tags: ps3, far-cry-4

I'm still having issues installing the game off the disc. I have more than enough space and the disc isn't scratched but it keeps getting stuck at 63%. Any advice on how to get this to work? Really want to play the game.

Comment: How much memory do you have, and how much is it asking for?

Comment: Well on the back of the game case it says I need 10.5GB and I went to my system information and I have 32GB left

Comment: When you say "keeps getting stuck", how long do you actually leave it, before determining that the game has frozen in installation?

Comment: Well like the screen keeps changing backgrounds so I don't think it's frozen but it gets to 63% and the longest I've let it sit was 2 hours

Answer (score 2):

If you have registered your game with Uplay, you can download the game and all updates through your Uplay desktop console. It takes a while, but if you cannot install with the disks, like me, download that way.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a post I found on GameFAQ of someone who had the exact same issue.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/795264-far-cry-4/70683167)

They were able to get it to work with the following steps:

1. Go to Settings > Network> Uncheck the 'Connect to Internet' box.
2. Install disk completely.
   (**note** that in can still take a while, still several hours rather than possibly over a day long...)
3. Turn your network settings back on.
4. Delete the patch if it starts to auto-download when the disk is inserted.
   (via the Notifications > Downloads menu)
5. Re-prompt updates by using the "Check for Updates" option on the Far Cry 4 game icon.

From what I've read online, it looks like it just tends to take an **atrociously** long amount of time. Hopefully those steps help a bit, but you might still have to muscle through quite a long install. (IF you decide to restart for any reason(s), it might be a good thing to make sure you don't have any residual FC4 files on your system before restarting)

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but it got stuck at 63% again

Comment: Tried what you suggested and still got to 63% then sat at 63% for two hours and then my ps3 reset

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to solve it by lowering the air temperature in the room by about 10°C and placing the console on a cold marble plate to cool it.

You should also try placing the PlayStation 3 on the other side; for example, I always place it vertically, so I placed it down horizontally.